# What's wrong with this program in C?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner of programming in C and I don't understand what's wrong with this simple program in C. I do not want that the program stops, then I create a goto statement to make it continue. The problem is that the program never stops (even when I press 2). This is the source code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int 
main(){

int i , num , d , times ,a ;
float next;
printf("Choose a number: ");
scanf("%i" , &num);

printf("Repeat number ... times: ");
scanf("%d" , &times);

for(i=0; i<times; i++){
    printf("%i\n" , num);
}

printf("Do you want to continue? (1=Yes   2=No) :");
scanf("%a" , &next);

if(a=1){
    goto jump;
}
else if(a=2){
    return 0;
}
else{
    printf("Invalid value");
    goto error;
}
jump:
    printf("Choose a number: ");
scanf("%i" , &num);

printf("Repeat number ... times: ");
scanf("%d" , &times);

for(i=0; i<times; i++){
    printf("%i\n" , num);
}

printf("Do you want to continue? (1=Yes   2=No) :");
scanf("%a" , &next);

if(a=1){
    goto jump;
}
else if(a=2){
    return 0;
}
else{
    printf("Invalid value");
    goto error;
}

error:
printf("Do you want to continue? (1=Yes   2=No) :");
scanf("%a" , &next);

if(a=1){
    goto jump;
}
else if(a=2){
    return 0;
}
else{
    printf("Invalid value");
    goto error;
}
}
```

Comment: First of all goto is obsolete. Take a book K & R  read it thoroughly and come back. Learn to use a debugger that will make half your problem solved

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour through the help system  and come back with a detailed description of what you expect from your program and a minimal example that exhibits your problem.

Comment: @rohitshrivastava, please keep SO a friendly place, I find barking at a beginner in the way you do, completely inappropriate.

Comment: `scanf("%a" , &next);` --> `scanf("%d" , &a);`, `if(a=1){` --> `if(a==1){`

Comment: For everyone's sanity (especially yours), please learn to indent your C code in an orthodox manner. There are numerous [indentation styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) that can be used; I recommend Allman (I use it) or 1TBS (many people prefer it), and eschew Pico style. You also need to learn to test the result of `scanf()`; if someone types a letter instead of a number, then you get bad behaviour from your code (and people _do_ make mistakes!). Terminate non-prompt outputs with newlines. Be consistent with 'no spaces before comma, space after comma'. Being consistent is good!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the way you compare numbers. On line 21, you checked if the user wants to continue with the following code:

```
if(a=1){
    goto jump;
```

The comparison operator is `==`. Using `=`, you are assigning 1 to variable a. Any non 0 value is evaluated as true, so what your code does is assign 1 to a, check that a is not 0, and goto jump.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `scanf` read a char, or a string, and this string is filled in `next`, but when you try to control user choice, which is in `next` you control the value of `a`. Try to change you code with this:

```
scanf("%d", &a);

...

if (a == 1) ...
```

Please remember also one single equal (=) is assignment, double equal (==) is testing for equality.

Comment: Glad it works. Check correct answer for every reader :)

Comment: Hei I have a doubt : if a is aqual to a number, I have to write a==number. 
But if I want to say that a is greater / lower than a number ? a> / < number is correct?

Comment: Yes, sir. And >= or <= for grester or equal than and so on. Please check correct answer if it was usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%a" , &next);
**scanf("%f" , &next);**

scanf("%i" , &num);
**scanf("%d" , &num);**



if(a==1){
    goto jump;
}
else if(a==2){
    return 0;
}

for(i=0; i<times; i++){
    printf("%d\n" , num);
}
```

Comment: Note that `%i` is a valid integer conversion format (and not necessarily wrong); it accepts decimal numbers that don't start with 0, octal numbers that start with 0, and hexadecimal numbers that start with 0x or 0X — all in a single conversion specifier. The `%d`, `%o`, `%x` and `%X` conversions accept only their designated base (decimal, octal, hex, hex). Indeed, `printf()` also accepts `%i` as a synonym for `%d` to help make `printf()` and `scanf()` formats more consistent (and the same goes for `%lf` — but `%f` means `float` in `scanf()` and `double` in `printf()` and that can't be helped).